# Error when getting website table data using python selenium - Multiple tables and Unable to locate element

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get info from brazilian stock market (BMF BOVESPA). The website has several tables, but my code is not being able to get them.

The code below aims to get all data from table "Ações em Circulação no Mercado" -> one of the last tables from webpage.

I have tried the ones below, but none worked for me:

content = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('//div[@id="div1"]')

and

table = browser.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="div1"]/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keBUX.jpg)/table/tbody'))

Thanks in advance for taking my question.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = "http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/cias-Listadas/Empresas-
Listadas/ResumoEmpresaPrincipal.aspx?codigoCvm=19348&idioma=pt-br"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
sleep(5) #wait website to reload
content = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('//div[@id="div1"]')
```

HTML can be found at attached picture

[image: HTML]

As alternative, the code below reaches the same website

```
url = "http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/cias-Listadas/Empresas-Listadas/BuscaEmpresaListada.aspx?idioma=pt-br"
Ticker='ITUB4'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_BuscaNomeEmpresa1_txtNomeEmpresa_txtNomeEmpresa_text"]')).send_keys(Ticker)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_BuscaNomeEmpresa1_btnBuscar"]')).click();
content = browser.find_element_by_id('div1')
```

Comment: Hello All, 

In the end, the webpage info is shown as iFrame and needs special tools. It is possible to find more information @ elementalselenium.com/tips/3-work-with-frames 

The solution was solved by @elrich bachman. 

Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selenium with Python documentation UnOfficial](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Hii there

Selenium provides the following methods to locate elements in a page:

```
find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector
```

Why your code doesnt work ? because you're not using correct correct code to locate element

you're using xpath inside css selector

```
content = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('//div[@id="div1"]') #this part is wrong
```

instead you can do this if you want to select div1

```
content = browser.find_element_by_id('div1')
```

here's the correct code

```
url = "http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/cias-Listadas/Empresas-

Listadas/BuscaEmpresaListada.aspx?idioma=pt-br"
Ticker='ITUB4'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_BuscaNomeEmpresa1_txtNomeEmpresa_txtNomeEmpresa_text"]')).send_keys(Ticker)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_BuscaNomeEmpresa1_btnBuscar"]')).click()
```

I tested it and it worked :)

Mark it as best answer if i helped you :)

Comment: Elrich, thanks for helping on this. I receive the error: 

"NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element"

For me its weird because the element is there. Don't know why selenium does not find the table data. Have it worked for you?

Tks again.

Comment: the link you've provided shows this "Essa página não existe ou não pode ser encontrada." so i am not able to figure out whats the problem if you can provide the link i can retry and help you with it .

Comment: Thx Elrich,

I wiill update code into question.

Please see last lines of question (below picture) updated.

Thx again

Comment: Thx for nth time for your attention, but just to confirm. Where you able to run --- content = browser.find_element_by_id('div1') --- in my new code? I didn't get the table content and received error message

Comment: Hey Elrich. Really sorry if I made myself confusing with the question. I did another one, trying to be more precise. You can find it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193756/unable-to-get-table-element-in-website-using-python-selenium

Tks again

Comment: do you use skype ? if so share your skype id i will add you because from my end code is working for me

Comment: Yes, sure! Pls find me @ ricardo.radaeli -> Full name Ricardo de Figueiredo Radaeli

Comment: here you go click this link to add me on skype https://join.skype.com/nePq9Rb5Bqw2