# Unable to get table element in website using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

The website below has several tables, but my code is not being able to get a specific one (nor any other table).

The code aims to get data from table "Ações em Circulação no Mercado" -> one of the last tables from webpage.

I have tried the code below and some alternatives, but none worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = "http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/cias-Listadas/Empresas-Listadas/BuscaEmpresaListada.aspx?idioma=pt-br"
Ticker='ITUB4'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
sleep(2) #Wait webpage to load
browser.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_BuscaNomeEmpresa1_txtNomeEmpresa_txtNomeEmpresa_text"]')).send_keys(Ticker)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_BuscaNomeEmpresa1_btnBuscar"]')).click();
sleep(2) #Wait webpage to load
browser.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_BuscaNomeEmpresa1_grdEmpresa_ctl01"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a')).click();
sleep(5) #Wait webpage to load

#This is not working
content = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('//div[@id="div1"]')

#This is not working as well
#browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="div1"]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]').text
```

The Table and Full HTML can be found here:

[image: Table]

[image: HTML]

HTML is:

```
<div id="div1">
                <div>
                    <h3>Ações em Circulação no Mercado</h3>
                    <div class="table-wrapper"><div class="scrollable"><table class="responsive">

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="3" class="text-center">19/04/2017</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Tipos de Investidores / Ações</td>
                                <td class="text-center">Quantidade</td>
                                <td class="text-center">Percentual</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td>Pessoas Físicas</td>
                                <td class="text-right">108.853</td>
                                <td class="text-right"> - </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Pessoas Jurídicas</td>
                                <td class="text-right">11.591</td>
                                <td class="text-right"> - </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Investidores Institucionais</td>
                                <td class="text-right">1.039</td>
                                <td class="text-right"> - </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Quantidade de Ações Ordinárias</td>
                                <td class="text-right">272.710.309</td>
                                <td class="text-right">8,21</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Quantidade de Ações Preferenciais</td>
                                <td class="text-right">3.141.058.175</td>
                                <td class="text-right">97,23</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Total de Ações</td>
                                <td class="text-right">3.413.768.484</td>
                                <td class="text-right">52,11</td>
                            </tr>

                            </tbody></table></div><div class="pinned"></div></div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hello All,

In the end, the webpage info is shown as iFrame and needs special tools. It is possible to find more information @ http://elementalselenium.com/tips/3-work-with-frames

The solution was solved by @elrich bachman.

Tks to all

Answer (score 1):

You wrote XPATH in CSS selector definition. You should locate 
`tables = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.responsive')`
if you want all tables, and then parse from them. OR
Use `browser.find_element_by_xpath(.//*[@id='div1']/div/table)` to locate exact table.

Comment: BTW, the correct way to locate by XPATH to your element is following:
`browser.find_element_by_xpath(//div[@id='div1']//table[@class='responsive'])`

Comment: Tks Karen. Have your solution worked on your comp? The first code to locate all tables gives me an empty variable and the solution in your comment gives me the error message: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='div1']//table[@class='responsive']"}

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

One quick correction you can make is to change this `content = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('//div[@id="div1"]')` to `content = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="div1"]')` because it actually is an xpath you're using.

The reason the second attempt is not working might be that the div1 element is not scrolled into view. Selenium does not interact well with elements that are not visible. So try this:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="div1"]')
# Force the element to be scrolled into view, even if you don't need its location.
location = element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
# Now Selenium can get its text.
text = element.text
```

Comment: Tks @Ron Norris. Both solutions are not working though. The error message for both cases are: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="div1"]"}

Very interesting your comments on scrolled view. Maybe the error is because there are 2 scrolls inside the same page. I will look for more info on this.

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

To locate the *WebElement* and extract the text **Pessoas Fisicas** you can use the following line of code :

```
content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[.,'Ações em Circulação no Mercado']//following::div[1]//table[@class='responsive']//tr//following-sibling::td[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

---

### Update (no code change)

The `xpath` expression :

```
//h3[.,'Ações em Circulação no Mercado']//following::div[1]//table[@class='responsive']//tr//following-sibling::td[1]
```

Shouldn't be within single quotes e.g. `'xpath_here'`. Put the xpression with in double quote e.g. `"xpath_here"`

See the working snapshot :

[image: tds]

Comment: Tks @DebanjanB. Your solution didn't work for me. Is it running good for you? I receive the following error:

InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //h3[.,'Ações em Circulação no Mercado']//following::div[1]//table[@class='responsive']//tr//following-sibling::td[1] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//h3[.,'Ações em Circulação no Mercado']//following::div[1]//table[@class='responsive']//tr//following-sibling::td[1]' is not a valid XPath expression. 

Tks!

Comment: @Ricardo Can you update the question with text based formatted HTML for a quick analysis?

Comment: Done. But maybe it is a webpage specific issue... Tks again

Comment: Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Not luck yet on my side. I added .py file and an Error Print Screen into Dropbox. Please take a look:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nm5wwpdglbgohex/AAC2ZBYdpwgBSsQ9ErooHIwRa?dl=0

Please let me know if this code works for you. Really tks again